Not working retry mechanism on Asynchronous @RabbitMqListener Method with Spring AMQP(RabbitMQ) [Solved]
Summarize the problem
I use Spring AMQP and I tried to apply SimpleRetryPolicy. Like this:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          max-attempts: 3

but it's not working on Asynchronous @RabbitMqListener Method with Spring AMQP(RabbitMQ). It's just an indefinite requeue.
Tried

default-requeue-rejected=true or false, throw AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException
-> not requeued
default-requeue-rejected=false, throw RuntimeException
-> not requeued
default-requeue-rejected=true, throw RuntimeException
-> indefinitely requeued

All retry did not work.
Code
In the receiveWasteTransaction method in the code below, i tested it by adding 'Exception' after saveAlarm.
    @Async
    @RabbitListener(queues = {"#{wasteCompleteQueue.name}", "#{wasteFlagQueue.name}", "#{wasteChangeStatusQueue.name}"})
    public CompletableFuture<Void> receiveWasteTransaction(@Payload AlarmPayload alarmPayload) {
        log.debug("receive complete transaction message: {}", alarmPayload);
        Alarm alarm = saveAlarm(alarmPayload);
        receive(alarmPayload.memberId(), AlarmResponse.fromEntity(alarm));
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }

    private void receive(Long memberId, AlarmResponse alarmResponse) {
        emitterRepository
                .findByMemberId(memberId)
                .ifPresentOrElse(
                        sseEmitter -> {
                            try {
                                sseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.event()
                                        .id(String.valueOf(alarmResponse.id()))
                                        .name(WASTE_TRANSACTION_ALARM_NAME)
                                        .data(alarmResponse));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                emitterRepository.deleteByMemberId(memberId);
                                throw new AlarmException(ErrorCode.ALARM_CONNECT_ERROR, e);
                            }
                        },
                        () -> log.error("Not Found Emitter"));
    }

Question

Is it because it becomes a block if I use retry?
It works fine in synchronous methods, but why doesn't it work in asynchronous methods?

Reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/async-returns.html

UPDATE(Solved)
just set concurrency... not using @Async with listener
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          max-attempts: 3
        concurrency: 5
        max-concurrency: 10

